# Center Website at small resolution

Tags: css, html, browser, center

i've got the following problem. I Have a website with all elements centered.
The Content Part is a div with the width of 1060px, margined 0 auto. Works fine so far.

The Problem is when i set the browser size to 1024 this div doesn't center but starts from the left side. This div also has an inner padding of 40px. When in the small resolution you can see the padding on the left but not the one of the right side..

long question short... what to do i have to do to have the website always being centered, no matter what size the browser window has..

Edit1:
The logic problem is that every browser places the website on the left "border" of the window when reducing the width of the browser window. Is there a workaround to prevent this? So that the browser "moves" the page "negative" beyond the left side of the browser ?

thanks in advance

Comment: that is a logical error in your thinking. you use a static width for your content. So when the width of the viewport get's smaller than the width of the content-div, there is no other change than to start from the left border and give a scrollbar. If you really want a centering for every possible browser size, then you must use dynamic measurements (for example %). But I wouldn't make the layout completely fluid, because that will destroy the layout in certain windows sizes. Have you thought about using media queries and defining the styles depending on the viewport size?

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
body {
width: 99%;
max-width: 1060px;
min-width: 800px;
margin: auto 0;
}
```

Using percentages is safer but it can cause issues with positioning and such. Minimize the risk by using min/max.

Comment: thanks for that, but i doesn't work either. the thing with the absolute width div's is right... is there a work around besides responsive designs ?

Comment: @sparks Responsive web-design is your best bet as a workaround. Read something on the ideas behind that concept.

Comment: man on resizing the window all the elements will float here and there because the body width is in percentage which will cause body width changed on resizing of window!

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib Using body was just an example. Lol

Comment: laugh out loud man it is only example....ha ha ha, oh man i am also laughing,  oh that was only example! hey man, give me place to hide. oh man that was an example only! :LOL if it was example though you learned something!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed width which is larger then your screen, then this will happen once you get a browser which is smaller.

Have you considered making it responsive, maybe having something like

```
.container{
  width:100%;
  max-width:1060px

/* then any other styles, margin etc */
}
```

That way your main container will resize with the browser?

responsive design by Ethan Marcotte is a great book to learn more on responsive websites.

[heres a link to a book apart](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design)

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way round? I commonly used something like `.wrapper { width: 50em; max-width: 95%; margin: 0 auto; }` to have a fixed-fluid layout.

Comment: @feeela depends on how its being built/designed. If a design has been done at say 1100px, Id have that as the max width, centred. then have it responsive on anything smaller then the designed/perfect size

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
width:100%;
height:0 auto !important;
background: /* Any Background */;
}
body {
position:relative; // no need of wrapper if use this
top:0;
width:1060px;
// other properties here but no margin properties
}

$(document).ready( function() {
var q = $("html").width();
var w = $("body").width();
if (q <= w) {
q = w;
}
var e = q/2;
var r = w/2;
var left = e-r;
$("body").css({ "left":left+"px" });
});
```

or if you don't like it!

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/centering-a-website/